# Why doesn't docker find a file I've added?

Tags: docker

So I've added a file using ADD in the docker file

```
...
ADD flvcheck /usr/local/bin/flvcheck
```

It build right and the file is there:

```
$ docker run --rm=true -ti image ls -l /usr/local/bin/flvcheck
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 1659908 May 20 07:56 /usr/local/bin/flvcheck
```

But When I try to run it I get:

```
$ docker run --rm=true -ti image /usr/local/bin/flvcheck
2014/05/20 08:43:25 no such file or directory
```

I did even install strace and use -D=true, but the problem is just that the file is being not found:

```
execve("/usr/local/bin/flvcheck", ["flvcheck"], [/* 8 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What is happening here? I can't find the issue (The file works ok in the host system and I can see it's contents within the docker

Answer (score 4):

I've found out that this was because of the architecture. The Container was running a x86_64 image (default debian:squeeze) and the file is in i386.

The red herring was because the file not found, did not referred to the file itself, but the file *loader*... now that's a useful error message...

To sort this out just install the i386 libraries. For the ubuntu base image adding this to the dockerfile will solve your problem:

```
 RUN apt-get install -y ia32-libs
```

For others (even newer [ubuntu images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)), this might get trickier.